# Regular expression-exclude and include some words

Tags: regex

I have multiple files with these kind of imports:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/pickadate/lib/themes/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../external/default.date.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scheduleCtrl_Helper_5.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="agenda_Helper.js"></script>
```

I want to find all imports that end with .js but not _5.js (5 or any number)

and also ignore imports from vendor and external.

I have this regexp which seems to work fine:

^(?!.*external).*[^\d].js".*$

so it excludes import containing external and those ending with a *number.js*

but how can I add multiple exclusion words ?
something like:

^(?!.*external|vendor).*[^\d].js".*$

Thx for your help

Comment: Something like `\b(?:src|href)="(?![^"]*(?:external|vendor))[^"]*[^"\d]\.js"`. What is the expected output?

Comment: OMG, how do you do that? it is exactly whant I wanted, thx you so much

Comment: See my explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
\b(?:src|href)="((?![^"]*(?:external|vendor))[^"]*[^"\d]\.js)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fjh3ac/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:src|href)` - either `src` or `href`
- `="` - a `="` string
- `((?![^"]*(?:external|vendor))[^"]*[^"\d]\.js)` - Group 1:

  - `(?![^"]*(?:external|vendor))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more chars other than `"` as many as possible followed with either `external` or `vendor`
  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `[^"\d]` - a char other than `"` and a digit
  - `\.js`  - a `.js` substring
- `"` - a `"` char.